# RAM vs EEPROM performance

Tags: memory, ram, eeprom

Currently I'm developing a project for an AVR ATMEGA8 board with IAR which has 1kb of RAM memory. I'm storing some values in the EEPROM as well.

My question is if it's a bad practice to read the values from EEPROM directly. I know I can save these values in RAM and then use them but I'd like to know the advantages and disadvantages of this practice.

Thank you!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on http://electronics.stackexchange.com/. That being said, it is likely just fine to read directly from the EEPROM. Although you have to RTFM and check EEPROM characteristics to be sure.

Comment: No problem, let me Google that for you. 30 seconds of Google reveals the following in the friendly MCU manual: "When the EEPROM is read, the CPU is halted for four clock cycles before the next instruction is executed."